# Android Content Provider With two Tables With Same Column Names

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm writing an Android Content Provider with a couple tables. Let's say we have one table named testData and one table named testDataInspector. In testData we have a column named createdDate and in testDataInspector we have another column name createdDate. I have found that in a content provider the SDK cannot find the column named testDataInspector.createdDate when there is already a testData.createdDate. I have found that I need to add a prefix of the table name to the column name in order to distinguish the different column names among the tables. When I want to query the contentProvider for the testDataInspector it will not find two column names of the same name in different tables. I have the correct URI's and are using the URI matcher correctly. My inserts work fine.

example :

(for table testData)

```
int creatorId = c.getColumnIndex(TestDataMetaData.CREATOR_ID_COLUMN_NAME);
int createdDate = c.getColumnIndex(TestDataMetaData.CREATED_DATE_COLUMN_NAME);
```

(for table testDataInspector)

```
int formName = c.getColumnIndex(TestDataInspectorMetaData.FORM_NAME_COLUMN_NAME);
int data = c.getColumnIndex(TestDataInspectorMetaData.DATA_COLUMN_NAME);
int creatorId = c.getColumnIndex(TestDataInspectorMetaData.CREATOR_ID_COLUMN_NAME);
int createdDate = c.getColumnIndex(TestDataInspectorMetaData.TESTDATA_CREATED_DATE_COLUMN_NAME);
```

Has anyone else come across this? I am wondering if it has anything to do with the pointers inside of SQLite. I have found this to be true when compiling an application in any SDK version greater than 2.2. I realize the ContentProviders are mostly used for, but necessarily the rule for one table at a time.

The other question I have if is it has something to do with the way the columns are aliased inside the ProjectionMap in the ContentProvider itself. I have worked with Content provders in the past but normally they are only one table. The project I am currently on will need a rather extensive database compared to what I am used to in the past. Any help with this question would be helpful as I found a fix and can't spend time playing with the whys.

Comment: How do you retrive c (Cursor) ?

Comment: I was just doing a managed query in the test client application. to keep the testing simple.

Answer (score 0):

OK this was my mistake. I apologize. This did have to do with the Projections Map in the content provider. I was not adding the correct alias for the column name inside the Hash Map. I apologize for creating any issues. To reference c I was doing a managed query inside the Activity as I was developing a simple client app to access the content provider.